# Option Delta Calculation - Local Vol Model vs Black-Scholes Model

Tags: finance

I am looking to get the greeks for option chain. Which model does work better for greeks calculation especially the delta. I am having issue with the Black-Scholes Model Delta since it always overstates the delta than the one actually implied by the market. How easy is it to implement the Local Vol Delta calculation? Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks for the link.

Comment: Since you posted at Quant SE, better delete this one to prevent wasted effort.